# How can I get my Discord Bot written in Javascript to send messages faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to know how to make my discord bot written in JavaScript more efficient at sending messages to a person/author or a server/channel. Is there something in code that I can do to make my bot send messages faster? I have a command handler like this:

```
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFile = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFile) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

let msg = message;

if(msg.content === 'something'){
        bot.commands.get('fileSomething').execute(message);
}
```

I have a folder named commands and I have the name of the file there, like:
Commands / fileSomething.js
and in that file there would be:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'commandsList',
    description: 'Sends a message saying "what?"',
    execute(message){
        message.channel.send(`What?`);
    }
}
```

I only keep bigger commands in files like that to keep everything organized. The smaller commands I do like this:

```
if(message.content === 'something') {
      message.channel.send(`what?`);
}
```

and I keep my commands separate like this:

```
if(message.content === 'something') {
      message.channel.send(`what?`);
}

if(message.content === 'something') {
      message.channel.send(`what?`);
}

if(message.content === 'something else') {
      message.channel.send(`Now really?`);
}
```

If anyone could help me out that would be really appreciated!

Comment: How fast are they at the moment? Do you roughly know a time, also what is your ping?

Answer (score 0):

What is the ping of your bot?
If you are unsure of how to check the bots ping, put this code into a command and it should tell you:

```
message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms.`)
```

If your ping is high it is an issue on your end, if not then you may have to look in futher

Comment: My latency is 32ms

Comment: is that bad ping?

Comment: No that is not bad ping, do you know how long it takes for the message to go through? @Hendin

Comment: It usually takes 1-3 seconds on some commands, though not all. Only the longer commands. Some with images